# Можно ли смещать карту на определенное расстояние при клике по маркеру?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть карта с маркерами. Маркеры могут находится близко к краю карты. Как при клике на маркер проверять, если он к краю ближе чем 100px*100px справа, то двигать карту (не центровать) на это расстояние.

```
 let marker = new Ymaps.Placemark([lat, lng], {}, {
      hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
      iconLayout: this.createMarkerLayout(group, '36px'),
      iconOffset: [-18, -18],
      iconShape: { type: 'Circle', coordinates: [18, 18], radius: 18 },
      iconColor: group[0].targeted ? '#FF6458' : '#1BA9F9',
      balloonLayout: this.createPopupLayout(group[0]),
      balloonOffset: [12, -22],
    })
    marker.events.add('click', e => {
      // думаю, где-то здесь надо что-то делать, так он центрует карту относительно метки
      this.map.panTo([lat, lng], {flying: false, safe: false})
    })
    this.markers.push(marker)
this.map.geoObjects.add(new Ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({ children: this.markers }))

createPopupLayout (board) {
return Ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(`
  <div class="custom-popup">....</div> `,
  {
    build: function () {
      this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this)
      this._$element = this.getParentElement().querySelector('.custom-popup')
      this._$element.style.top = `-${(this._$element.offsetHeight)}px`
      this._$element.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this))
    },
    clear: function () {
      this._$element.removeEventListener('click', this.click)
      this.constructor.superclass.clear.call(this)
    },
    click: async function ({target}) {
      const root = this.getParentElement().querySelector('.custom-popup')
    },
  })}
```

Comment: Так включённая по умолчанию опция балуна autoPan и так смещает карту, если отрывающийся балун не помещается в границах карты. А при клике на маркер у вас балун, вижу, открываться должен вроде как. Или затея именно прям в 100px и с балуном никак не связана?

Comment: Это кастомный балун, добавила к нему код. Почему-то с ним не срабатывает autoPan. Поэтому ищу решение просто сдвигать карту на размер балуна, т.к. он постоянен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы кастомные балуны учитывались опцией [autoPan](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/IBalloon#autoPan), им следует правильно задавать форму через [getShape](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/ILayout#getShape). [Рабочий пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan/) есть в нашей песочнице.